# Grand Totals Not Updating Upon Delete

Tags: angular

I am using a getter to update the grand totals. When I click on the deleteItem button, the grand total isn't updated and the table cell displays the same grand total as before even though items have been removed. How can I fix this?

In the HTML:

```
<form name="yourForm" [formGroup]="yourForm">
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
<td><td></td>
<button type="button" (click)="deleteItem(i)" class="deletebtn">X</button></td>
<td>{{item.quantity}} </td>
<td>{{item.product_price }} </td>
<td>{{item.quantity * item.product_price }}</td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td><b>Grand Total</b> </td><td><b>{{grandTotal }}</b></td></tr>
</table>
```

In the component:

```
totals = [];
get grandTotal() {

let i;
let sub_total = 0;
let grand_total = 0;
if  (this.isSubmitted == true) {
 if (typeof this.product_price  !== "undefined" && typeof this.quantity  !== "undefined") {
                                sub_total = this.product_price * this.quantity;
                                this.totals.push(sub_total);
                        }
                }
                          
                                
                for (i = 0; i < this.totals.length; i++) {
                        grand_total += this.totals[i];
                }
        this.isSubmitted = false;
        return grand_total;
}

deleteItem(i){
this.totals = [];
this.isSubmitted = true;
this.grandTotal;
this.items.splice(i,1);
this.setStorageItems(this.items);

}
```

Comment: you need to assign the new value to this.grandTotal

Comment: I added this.grandTotal to deleteItem(i) and it still doesn't update properly.

Answer (score 0):

this.totals u need to initialize to [] before pushing values into it.

Comment: I edited my post to reflect the changes I made in response to the comments. It's still not working.

Comment: I don't need the full-blown code. I just need some pseudo code and then I could take it from there.

Comment: It updates the grand total with the price that has just been deleted.